# What causes the yellow and brown spots on our sour cherry tree?

Tags: botany, trees, infection, fruit

So at the end of spring (maybe at the beginning of summer) our sour cherry tree started producing these yellowish/brownish spots on its leaves. Can you help me identify the couse of this? What can we do against it? I cannot see any bugs on it, my best guess would be some kind of a fungus, but I am way far from being an expert. Thank you in forward for the answers!

**Edit**: I am located in Hungary. The brown spots are not bigger than my nails, but the yellow area can cover even the whole leaves. Also, the capillaries visible on the leaves can turn red, as you can see on the pictures. Unfortunately, the exact species of the cherry is unknown to me.

[image: sour cherry spots 1]
[image: sour cherry spots 2]
[image: sour cherry spots 3]

Comment: how rich is the soil? is do other plants get big or do they stay small and pale white, like for a limestone soil and sandy mineral soil? brown spots in plants is an indicator of phosphate deficiency. phosophorous deficiency also produces light veins. check a deficiency leaf chart. https://www.pinterest.nz/maryinnz/phosphorus-deficiency/ it could be something else. https://www.google.com/search?q=deficiency+leaf&tbm=isch

Comment: it may also be dryness. where I live, cherries go thirsty and have messed up leaves after june, but they come back strong again the year after. they are early summer plants in hot countries and keep sugar in the tree for next spring. it can be root damage also or top soil dryness or defficiency or other causes.

Comment: also to note is that there is an inviasive species on european cherries from aisa which is a bug which lays eggs in every single cherry and causes early cherry rot. perhaps hungary freezes enough in the winter to keep their numbers down. Asiatic cherry fly (Drosophila suzukii)

Answer (score -1):

The tree is most likely sick. Plant diseases take years to develop versus diseases in animals caused by either bacteria, viruses, or parasites. This is because the tree has thick cell walls that can be a huge barrier hindering viral infection. Another thing is that trees lack a circulatory system and rely on partial water pressure from the air to draw water from the roots up to the leaves.

Your tree might have a virus that is slowly killing it. Which insects are endemic to your region? We can deduce the virus if we know the main types of bugs living in your area.